# What happens to disaster relief money?

Tags: united-states, budget

Last year, apparently, [the United States spent an (unbudgeted) $140 billion on disaster relief](https://thehill.com/policy/finance/411215-disasters-become-big-chunk-of-us-deficit) for areas hit by hurricanes. What exactly happens to this money? What is it spent on?

Comment: I think you mean to ask about just the money spent by the United States *federal government*.  Far more than that was spent by private entities (such as charities, insurance companies) and local governments.  A bit of clarification of your question would go a long way.